# How UIApplication knows when a UIWindow is created in the app?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiwindow, uiapplication

In the `UIApplicationDelegate`'s `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` I have the following code:

```
NSLog(@"%d\n", [UIApplication sharedApplication].windows.count);

self.mainWindow = [[UIWindow alloc]initWithFrame:[UIScreen mainScreen].bounds];

NSLog(@"%d\n", [UIApplication sharedApplication].windows.count);
```

(`mainWindow` is a `@property` declared in the header)

The first `NSLog` prints out `0` while the second prints `1`.

How `UIApplication` knows that a window is created and initialized in the application?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While we don't have the source code to be 100% sure, it would seem that the initializer of `UIWindow` is written to tell `UIApplication` that it has been created. It's simply part of Apple's implementation of the two classes.

Comment: More specifically, the `UIWindow` class keeps an array of all created windows which all windows add themselves to in their initializers and `[UIApplication sharedApplication] windows]` calls a class method on `UIWindow` that filters and returns that array.

Comment: @dan - How do you know this? None of that is in the public API.

Comment: I disassembled UIKit with Hopper because I was curious about what it did specifically.  Obviously it's an implementation detail which can change at any time and can't be relied on.

Comment: @dan Nice. It makes sense. I was just curious how you knew.

Comment: @dan Check [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/37662901/2415822) with regard to private methods.

Comment: @dan An interesting aspect of this is that you can swizzle `UIWindow` `init` and `dealloc` methods and gain access to the system windows (status bar & keyboard, which were hidden from `UIApplication.windows` in iOS 7). This can be used to take screenshot of your app programatically, including status bar & keyboard. Not for production of course.

Comment: @Sulthan You can also get those windows by calling the private `+[UIWindow allWindowsIncludingInternalWindows:onlyVisibleWindows:]` method passing `YES` to the first parameter.

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking for a specific function (to hook, or are just curious), most of the application setup in `UIWindow` is performed in the [`- (void)_createContextIfNecessaryForCurrentApplicationState;`](https://github.com/nst/iOS-Runtime-Headers/blob/master/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/UIWindow.h#L244) method and the [`NSISEngineDelegate`](https://github.com/nst/iOS-Runtime-Headers/blob/master/protocols/NSISEngineDelegate.h) protocol methods.

Answer (score 0):

Apple [doc](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIApplication_Class/) says

> When an app is launched, the system calls the UIApplicationMain
>   function; among its other tasks, **this function creates a singleton
>   UIApplication object**. Thereafter you access the object by calling the
>   sharedApplication class method.  A major role of your app’s
>   application object is to handle the initial routing of incoming user
>   events. It dispatches action messages forwarded to it by control
>   objects (instances of the UIControl class) to appropriate target
>   objects. **The application object maintains a list of open windows
>   (UIWindow objects)** and through those can retrieve any of the app’s
>   UIView objects.